# Problem with "Vim omni-completion for PHP"

Tags: php, vim

I use vim with omni-completion for php and it works well but not for all built-in functions

It does not work with all the new built-in functions added **'i'** like  `mysqli_fetch_array()` , but works for all functions without 'i' like `mysql_fetch_array()`

thank you.

Comment: Don't you have to update your 'tags' file? Search for 'Exuberant Ctags'.

Answer (score 0):

This [omnicomplete script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3171) will do the trick.